# Query MySQL: Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-select

Tenho uma Query em MySQL que só me retorna `Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query`.

Segue a mesma:

```
 select log_logradouro.ufe_sg, log_localidade.LOC_NU, log_localidade.LOC_NU_SUB, log_localidade.loc_no, log_bairro.bai_no, CONCAT(log_logradouro.tlo_tx, " ", log_logradouro.log_no) as log_no, log_logradouro.cep, log_logradouro.log_complemento,"" AS nome, log_localidade.MUN_NU, log_num_sec.SEC_NU_INI, log_num_sec.SEC_NU_FIM, log_num_sec.SEC_IN_LADO

from log_logradouro, log_localidade, log_bairro, log_num_sec

where log_logradouro.loc_nu= log_localidade.loc_nu and log_logradouro.bai_nu_ini=log_bairro.bai_nu and log_logradouro.log_sta_tlo ="s"

union

select log_logradouro.ufe_sg, log_localidade.LOC_NU, log_localidade.LOC_NU_SUB, log_localidade.loc_no, log_bairro.bai_no, log_logradouro.log_no as log_no, log_logradouro.cep, log_logradouro.log_complemento,"" AS nome, log_localidade.MUN_NU, log_num_sec.SEC_NU_INI, log_num_sec.SEC_NU_FIM, log_num_sec.SEC_IN_LADO

from log_logradouro, log_localidade, log_bairro, log_num_sec

where log_logradouro.loc_nu= log_localidade.loc_nu and log_logradouro.bai_nu_ini=log_bairro.bai_nu and log_logradouro.log_sta_tlo ="n"

union

SELECT LOC.UFE_SG, LOC.LOC_NU, LOC.LOC_NU_SUB, LOC.LOC_NO, "" AS BAI_NO, "" AS LOG_NO, LOC.CEP, "" AS LOG_COMPLEMENTO, "" AS NOME, LOC.MUN_NU AS MUN_NU, SEC.SEC_NU_INI AS SEC_NU_INI, SEC.SEC_NU_FIM AS SEC_NU_FIM, SEC.SEC_IN_LADO AS SEC_IN_LADO

FROM LOG_LOCALIDADE AS LOC, log_num_sec AS SEC
WHERE LOC.CEP IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT LOC.UFE_SG, LOC.LOC_NU AS LOC_NU, LOC.LOC_NU_SUB AS LOC_NUM_SUB, LOCSUB.LOC_NO AS LOC_NO, LOC.LOC_NO AS BAI_NO, "" AS LOG_NO, LOC.CEP, "" AS LOG_COMPLEMENTO, "" AS NOME, LOC.MUN_NU AS MUN_NU, SEC.SEC_NU_INI AS SEC_NU_INI, SEC.SEC_NU_FIM AS SEC_NU_FIM, SEC.SEC_IN_LADO AS SEC_IN_LADO

FROM LOG_LOCALIDADE AS LOC, LOG_LOCALIDADE AS LOCSUB, log_num_sec AS SEC

WHERE LOC.CEP IS NOT NULL

AND LOC.LOC_NU_SUB IS NOT NULL

AND LOC.LOC_NU_SUB = LOCSUB.LOC_NU

union

select log_cpc.ufe_sg, log_localidade.LOC_NU, log_localidade.LOC_NU_SUB, log_localidade.loc_no,"" 
as bai_no, log_cpc.cpc_endereco as log_no, log_cpc.cep,"" as log_complemento,cpc_no AS nome, log_localidade.MUN_NU, log_num_sec.SEC_NU_INI, log_num_sec.SEC_NU_FIM, log_num_sec.SEC_IN_LADO

from log_cpc, log_localidade, log_num_sec

where log_cpc.loc_nu=log_localidade.loc_nu

union

select log_grande_usuario.ufe_sg, log_grande_usuario.LOC_NU, log_localidade.LOC_NU_SUB, log_localidade.loc_no, log_bairro.bai_no as bai_no, log_grande_usuario.gru_endereco as log_no, log_grande_usuario.cep,"" as log_complemento,gru_no AS nome, log_localidade.MUN_NU AS MUN_NU, log_num_sec.SEC_NU_INI AS SEC_NUM_INI, log_num_sec.SEC_NU_FIM AS SEC_NUM_FIM, log_num_sec.SEC_IN_LADO AS SEC_IN_LADO

from log_grande_usuario, log_localidade, log_bairro, log_num_sec

where log_grande_usuario.loc_nu=log_localidade.loc_nu and log_grande_usuario.bai_nu = log_bairro.bai_nu

union

select log_unid_oper.ufe_sg, log_localidade.LOC_NU, log_localidade.LOC_NU_SUB, log_localidade.loc_no, log_bairro.bai_no as bai_no, log_unid_oper.uop_endereco as log_no, log_unid_oper.cep,"" as log_complemento, uop_no AS nome, log_localidade.MUN_NU AS mun_nu, log_num_sec.SEC_NU_INI AS SEC_NUM_INI, log_num_sec.SEC_NU_FIM AS SEC_NUM_FIM, log_num_sec.SEC_IN_LADO AS SEC_IN_LADO

from log_unid_oper, log_localidade, log_bairro, log_num_sec

where log_unid_oper.loc_nu=log_localidade.loc_nu and log_unid_oper.bai_nu = log_bairro.bai_nu;
```

Este é o DER da base de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está errado na minha Query, que não executa?

Comment: Veja no manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: possível problema de *timeout*, a query demorou demais para ser executada. Veja como aumentar o limite de *timeout* para conseguir executar, ou melhore a performance da query